# Keras image classification: High accuracy shown but low on test images

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to do some image classification on the Caltech101 dataset. I used several pretrained models in Keras. I used some augmentation on the training set:

```
train_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
                    rescale=1./255, rotation_range=15,
                                   width_shift_range=0.1,
                                   height_shift_range=0.1,
                                   shear_range=0.01,
                                   zoom_range=[0.9, 1.25],
                                   horizontal_flip=False,
                                   vertical_flip=False,
                                   fill_mode='reflect',
                                   data_format='channels_last',
                                   brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5])
    validation_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                    train1_dir,  # Source directory for the training images
                    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
                    batch_size=batch_size)

    validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                    validation_dir, # Source directory for the validation images
                    target_size=(image_size, image_size),
                    batch_size=batch_size)
```

I also used some early stopping (stop after 100 epochs):

```
es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=100)
    mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model_%s_%s.h5' % (dataset_name, model_name), monitor='val_acc', mode='max', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
    callbacks = [es, mc]
```

At first I train the last layer:

```
base_model.trainable = False
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      base_model,
      keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
      keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001),
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    epochs = 10000
    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.n // batch_size
    validation_steps = validation_generator.n // batch_size
    history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                                  steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
                                  epochs=epochs,
                                  workers=4,
                                  validation_data=validation_generator,
                                  validation_steps=validation_steps, 
                                  callbacks=callbacks)
```

Then I train the previous layers, following the Keras tutorial:

```
# After top classifier is trained, we finetune the layers of the network
base_model.trainable = True
# Let's take a look to see how many layers are in the base model
print("Number of layers in the base model: ", len(base_model.layers))
# Fine tune from this layer onwards
fine_tune_at = 1
# Freeze all the layers before the `fine_tune_at` layer
for layer in base_model.layers[:fine_tune_at]:
    layer.trainable =  False

model.compile(optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
epochs = 10000
history_fine = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                                   steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch,
                                   epochs=epochs,
                                   workers=4,
                                   validation_data=validation_generator,
                                   validation_steps=validation_steps, 
                                   callbacks=callbacks
                                   )
```

Finally, after the model has finished training, I test it manually on a separate test set

```
label_list = train_generator.class_indices
    numeric_to_class = {}
    for key, val in label_list.items():
        numeric_to_class[val] = key
    total_num_images = 0
    acc_num_images = 0
    with open("%s_prediction_%s.txt" % (dataset_name, model_name), "wt") as fid:
        fid.write("Label list:\n")
        for label in label_list:
            fid.write("%s," % label)
        fid.write("\n")
        fid.write("true_class,predicted_class\n")
        fid.write("--------------------------\n")
        for label in label_list:
            testing_dir = os.path.join(test_dir, label)
            for img_file in os.listdir(testing_dir):
                img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(testing_dir, img_file))
                img_resized = cv2.resize(img, (image_size, image_size), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)                
                img1 = np.reshape(img_resized, (1, img_resized.shape[0], img_resized.shape[1], img_resized.shape[2]))
                pred_class_num = model.predict_classes(img1)
                pred_class_num = pred_class_num[0]
                true_class_num = label_list[label]                
                predicted_label = numeric_to_class[pred_class_num]               
                fid.write("%s,%s\n" % (label, predicted_label))
                if predicted_label == label:
                    acc_num_images += 1
                total_num_images += 1

    acc = acc_num_images / (total_num_images * 1.0)
```

I had to do this because the library does not output F1 score. However what I found out is that the val_acc goes up very high (about 0.8) but during the test phase after training the accuracy is very low (about 0.1 I think). I do not understand why this is so. Please help me, thank you very much.

UPDATE 15/10/2019: I tried to just train a linear svm on top of the network without finetuning anything and I got 70% accuracy on Caltech101 using VGG16 (with RMSProp optimizer). However I'm not sure if this is the best choice.

UPDATE 2: I used the preprocessing part suggested by Daniel Moller on my custom dataset (about 450 images, 283 class "open", 203 class "closed", and got this accuracy and loss when using early stopping with patience=100, just training the last layer with:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  base_model,
  keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
  keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])
```

[image: Accuracy]

[image: Loss]

UPDATE 3: I tried to use the last fully connected layers in VGG16 also, and added dropout layer after each of them, with the dropout rate (the rate that is set to 0)
 of 60%, and patience=10 (for early stopping):

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE, \
                                               include_top=True, \
                                               weights='imagenet')
base_model.layers[-3].Trainable = True
base_model.layers[-2].Trainable = True
fc1 = base_model.layers[-3]
fc2 = base_model.layers[-2]
predictions = keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
dropout1 = Dropout(0.6)
dropout2 = Dropout(0.6)
x = dropout1(fc1.output)
x = fc2(x)
x = dropout2(x)
predictors = predictions(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictors)
```

And I got the highest validation accuracy of 0.93750, test accuracy: 0.966216. Graphs: 
[image]
[image: Accuracy]

Comment: Isn't the amount of epochs a bit too much? Why use averageglobalpooling and not maxpooling? Don't you have an extremely overfitted network (because of so many epochs too)? Try using regularization techniques such as dropout and l2.

Comment: @CeliusStingher Hi I use early stopping to stop if there is no improvement after 100 epochs so the number of epochs is just the maximum number. I use averageglobalpooling according to a beginner tutoral on Keras. I thought that if both the train and validation accuracy is high then it would be all right ?

Comment: Yes, if both are high then it is OK, however you have a big difference between, that should probably be solved with regularization techniques.

Comment: @CeliusStingher But if both are high (>= 90%) then how can there be a big difference between them ? :)

Comment: If you could post the history of your metrics/losses it would be helpful. Although you have a lot of information here, nothing shows a hint of what can be wrong.

Comment: @DanielMöller I have updated the graphs

Comment: So, the problem seems really just how you load your images.

Comment: @DanielMöller but now when I run again the result did not get that good, I wonder why ? (I divided into train-val-test)

Comment: @DanielMöller The results seem okay, however when I divide the data into 10-fold for cross validation, with each fold, I divide the train into a train-val set and use early stopping on val set, the model sometimes classify everything as just one class (1 or 2 times over 10-fold on average). Do you know why this is the case ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Main issue seems to be here:

You forgot to rescale `1/255.` when you open the images for prediction in:

```py
.....
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(testing_dir, img_file))
img_resized = cv2.resize(img, (image_size, image_size), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
img1 = np.reshape(img_resized, 
                  (1, img_resized.shape[0], img_resized.shape[1], img_resized.shape[2]))

#you will probably need:
img1 = img1/255.

pred_class_num = model.predict_classes(img1)
...........
```

Also, notice that `cv2` will open images in `BGR` format, while Keras may be opening them in `RGB`.

- Get images from the Keras generator
- Get images opened by you
- Plot these images to check if they look ok (or at least the same, if everything is BGR, it's not a problem although all plots will look funny)

Example:

```
keras_train = train_generator[0][0] #first image from first batch
keras_val = validation_generator[0][0]

img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(testing_dir, img_file))
img_resized = cv2.resize(img, (image_size, image_size), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA) 
img1 = np.reshape(img_resized, 
                  (1, img_resized.shape[0], img_resized.shape[1], img_resized.shape[2]))    
your_image = img1[0]/255. #first image from your batch rescaled
```

Plot these images with `matplotlib`.
Also make sure they have the same range:

```
plt.imshow(keras_train)
plt.plot()
plt.imshow(keras_val)
plt.plot()
plt.imshow(your_image)
plt.plot()
print(keras_train.max(), keras_val.max(), img1.max())
```

You may need to use `np.flip(images, axis=-1)` to transform BGR into RGB.

## Hints for importing keras models

If you imported base model from keras, you should import the preprocessing from the same module, as well as use Keras image opener. This would eliminate possible mismatches:

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.preprocessing import image #use this instead of cv2   
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input #use this in the generators
```

In both generators, use the preprocessing function:

```
#no rescale, only preprocessing function
train_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
                               rotation_range=15,
                               width_shift_range=0.1,
                               height_shift_range=0.1,
                               shear_range=0.01,
                               zoom_range=[0.9, 1.25],
                               horizontal_flip=False,
                               vertical_flip=False,
                               fill_mode='reflect',
                               data_format='channels_last',
                               brightness_range=[0.5, 1.5],
                               preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
validation_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
                               preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
```

Load and preprocess your images for prediction:

```
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(image_size,image_size))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)
```

More in: https://keras.io/applications/

## Other possibilities

But there could be several other things like:

- Very strong overfitting, your patience for the early stopper is 100! Usually this is a very high number. But the only way to confirm this is to check whether the val_acc is rising too much compared with the best one.

  - Suggestion: reload the best model saved by `ModelCheckpoint` before you start predicting
  - Suggestion: post the acc history so we can see whether it's bad
- Does the base model have `BatchNormalization` layers? - When you freeze a batch normalization layer, it will keep the `moving_mean` and `moving_variance` unchanged, but these values were trained with a different data. If your data doesn't have the same mean and variance, your model will train well, but validation will be a disaster

  - Suggestion: see whether the validation loss/acc is terribly wrong since the beginning
  - Suggestion: don't freeze the `BatchNormalization` layers in the base model (iterate over the layers and freeze only the other types)
  - Suggestion: if you happen to know the database with which the base model was trained, compare your data mean and variation with that database's mean and variation (treat each channel individually)

Comment: Hi. I did try to divide by 255, however the values would then be from 0 to 1 so it would not be an integer anymore so I got an error on that.

Comment: Well, you are rescaling for training, you definitely must rescale for prediction.

Comment: Okay I will try to do that.

Comment: Ideally, if base model was imported from keras, you should also load `preprocess_input` from the same module you imported the model. Instead of rescaling, you'd have the exact preprocessing necessary for that model (You will need to use this same preprocessing in the generators and in your image)

Comment: @DangManhTruong, I updated the question showing how to use Keras preprocessing when you import a keras model.